# Excel's equivalent of Python's MAP

Tags: python, excel, mapreduce

I'm trying to find a way to apply a formula to all the cells in an array automatically (without needing to write it for the first cell and then dragging it down / using keyboard shortcuts to copy it to the underneat cells).
This is quite similar to python's "map" function, which is conceptually associated to the "reduce" and the "filter" functions in python.

Since there is a FILTER function in excel, which works just like python's FILTER, I'm wondering if there is a function that works like python's "map".

In practical terms, I can write "`=FILTER(name;condition on the name)`", but I don't find any practical way to write "`=MAP(name;function on the name)`" where the name is defined in the name manager and associated to a certain range (e.g.: name `= A1:A10`)

---

Here is a small **EXAMPLE**

I have this table:

**table01**

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Office | Notes |
| 2 | Rome |  |
| 3 | Milan |  |
| 4 | Milan |  |
| 5 | Turin |  |
| 6 | Rome | note |

There is a Name called "offices" which is associated to range A2:A6 and another one, called "notes" which is associated to range B2:B6.

I also have this routing table (in the same sheet for simplicity)

**table02**

|  | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | Person | Giovanni | Marco | Carlo |
| 8 | Office | Rome | Milan | Turin |

I want to obtain a new array containing the contacts that are related to the "offices" array with the only exeption that IF the office is ROME AND there is no note, then the contact will be Milan's office's contact (Marco):

**table03**

|  | G |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Contact |
| 2 | Marco |
| 3 | Marco |
| 4 | Marco |
| 5 | Carlo |
| 6 | Giovanni |

I have prepared the function that has to be applied to the single cell  (G2):

**funct01(colnum=2)**
"`=IF(AND(A2="Rome";ISBLANK(B2));OFFSET($E$8;-1;0);OFFSET($B$7;0;MATCH(A2;$D$8:$F$8)))`"

If I drag this down for 4 more cells (or use a keyboard shortcut to do the same thing), I obtain the correct output, so you can see it as a "black-box-function".

Problem is that when the array of the offices (**table01**) is updated, inserting a new row with a new office, the output array (**table03**) does not change its size automatically: I have to restart from G2 and drag down again for 5 more cells instead of four. I want this to be automatic.

Since I can type on G2 something like:

**funct02**
"`=FILTER(offices;NOT(offices="Rome"))`" and this automatically returns:

**table04**

|  | G |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Contact |
| 2 | Milan |
| 3 | Milan |
| 4 | Turin |

I would expect something working *like*:

**funct03**

"`=MAP(offices;**funct01(offices)**)`"

To return *exactly* **table03**.
Please note that, even if in general, **funct01** is a function of both "offices" and "notes", in this particular case, "notes" can be derived directly by offices (simply with `OFFSET(offices;0;1)`) so it is actually only a function of "offices".

---

Thank you for your time and attention, I'm sorry if my question was already answered elsewhere or if the solution was obvious. I've tried to look up on the internet and found some work-arounds but I did never find the exact thing I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In G2 put:

```
=IF((Offices="rome")*(Notes=""),$E$7,INDEX($D$7:$F$7,MATCH(Offices,$D$8:$F$8,0)))
```

Is should spill down the matches.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Scott. This is a solid way to perform routing that I didn't know about. But what about possible additional rules, like the one regarding the potential absence of the note? (If the office is ROME and there is no note, then the contact should be MARCO, not GIOVANNI) Can this be solved easily with the INDEX function?

Comment: I edited it to return that.  you may need to refresh the page

Comment: Thank you very much Scott. The "rules" thing was probably dumb to ask. The main thing was about the routing and it works just fine. I'll need to study a bit this Index+Match combination to master it but it works and it's simple and that's the important thing. Thank you very much!

Comment: If this worked please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.